# flexslider main image not loading in bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I have flexslider added into a bootstrap tab. But when i click on the tab it shows the thumbnails but not the main image.

I have created a test fiddle over here
http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/w39rzo69/6/

I did some research and found that adding resize will fix it, but it didnt seem to work for me

```
$('.flexslider').resize();
```

I need to make sure the complete slider loads when i move the tabs..

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You are initializing the slider while `.tab-pane` is hidden. Either initialize it or just trigger a resize on tab show event:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-target="#settings"]', function (e) {
    $('#slider').resize();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w39rzo69/8/)

Comment: @LiveEn I'm glad I was able to help